# java program that draws a fixed polygon

Tags: java, eclipse

I am writing a program that draws a fixed polygon with certain points and tells whether or not the mouse point is inside or outside of the polygon. I have no idea where i need to move code to so I can fix these errors. I'm pretty sure something is just in the wrong spot. This is what I have right now:

```
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.event.MouseAdapter;
import java.awt.event.MouseEvent;
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Point;
import java.awt.Polygon;

public class Ch3PA extends JFrame {

    Polygon polygon = new Polygon();
    Point point = new Point(0, 0);
    boolean inside = false;
    private PaintPanel paintPanel = new PaintPanel();

    public PaintPanel()
    {
        add(paintPanel);

        static class PaintPanel extends JPanel
        {       
            polygon.addPoint(40, 20);
            polygon.addPoint(70, 40);
            polygon.addPoint(60, 80);
            polygon.addPoint(45, 45);
            polygon.addPoint(20, 60);

             @addMouseMotionListener(new MouseAdapter()
             {
                public void mouseMoved(MouseEvent e)
                {
                    point.x = e.getX();
                    point.y = e.getY();
                    if (polygon.contains(e.getX(), e.getY()))
                    {
                        inside = true;
                        repaint();
                    }
                    else 
                    {
                        inside = false;
                        repaint();              
                    }
                }
            });
        }
    }

    protected void paintComponent(Graphics g){
        super.paintComponents(g);
        g.drawPolygon(polygon);
        if (inside)
        {
            g.drawString(inside ? "Mouse point is in the polygon"    :          "Mouse point is not in the polygon", point.x, point.y);
            repaint();
        }               
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Ch3PA frame = new Ch3PA();
        frame.setTitle("Ch3PA");
        frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.setSize(200, 200);
        frame.setVisible(true);         
    }   
}
```

Comment: Your code makes no sense.  You define a class called `Ch3PA`, but then define a constructor (for this class) called `PaintPanel`, which "seems" to a inner class you're trying to make with in it ...

Comment: It looks like she is copying someone else's code, but doing so poorly and without thought. This will never work as a method of learning to program. Instead try to copy ideas found in other programs, but write your own code.

Comment: Where are you adding your mouse listener? I would add it to the JPanel, there is no point of having the unused method.

Answer (score 2):

This...

```
public class Ch3PA extends JFrame {

    //...
    public PaintPanel()
```

Makes no sense.  You've defined a class called `Ch3PA`, but defined a constructor called `PaintPanel` for it

Then you define a class within the constructor....

```
static class PaintPanel extends JPanel
{

    polygon.addPoint(40, 20);
    polygon.addPoint(70, 40);
    polygon.addPoint(60, 80);
    polygon.addPoint(45, 45);
    polygon.addPoint(20, 60);



 @addMouseMotionListener(new MouseAdapter()
 {
    public void mouseMoved(MouseEvent e)
    {
        point.x = e.getX();
        point.y = e.getY();

        if (polygon.contains(e.getX(), e.getY()))
        {
            inside = true;
            repaint();
        }
            else 
            {
                inside = false;
                repaint();

        }
    }

});
```

Even if this was legal, the `polygon.addPoint` won't work, because you're trying to execute code outside of a executable context (method, constructor, `static` block)

`@addMouseMotionListener` is illegal syntax, you shouldn't be lead with `@`

Don't call `repaint();` inside any paint method, this will consume your CPU with never ending repaints

You're calling `super.paintComponents` <- Note the `s`, this is not the method your are looking for.  You should be calling `super.paintComponent`, but I suspect your IDE throw a fit and didn't know how to resolve it.  There is where the `@Override` annotation is so helpful, but I doubt, given all the other issues, it really would have helped immeditatly

Start by defining you `PaintPanel`, define it's operations and responsibilities...

```
public class PaintPanel extends JPanel {

    Polygon polygon = new Polygon();
    Point point = new Point(0, 0);
    boolean inside = false;

    public PaintPanel() {

        polygon.addPoint(40, 20);
        polygon.addPoint(70, 40);
        polygon.addPoint(60, 80);
        polygon.addPoint(45, 45);
        polygon.addPoint(20, 60);

        addMouseMotionListener(new MouseAdapter() {
            public void mouseMoved(MouseEvent e) {
                point.x = e.getX();
                point.y = e.getY();

                if (polygon.contains(e.getX(), e.getY())) {
                    inside = true;
                    repaint();
                } else {
                    inside = false;
                    repaint();

                }
            }

        });
    }

    protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {

        super.paintComponent(g);

        g.drawPolygon(polygon);

        if (inside) {
            g.drawString(inside ? "Mouse point is in the polygon" : "Mouse point is not in the polygon", point.x, point.y);
        }

    }

}
```

Now, add this to some container

```
EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        try {
            UIManager.setLookAndFeel(UIManager.getSystemLookAndFeelClassName());
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException | InstantiationException | IllegalAccessException | UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }

        JFrame frame = new JFrame("Testing");
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.add(new PaintPanel());
        frame.pack();
        frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }
});
```

## Runnable example...

```
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import java.awt.Point;
import java.awt.Polygon;
import java.awt.event.MouseAdapter;
import java.awt.event.MouseEvent;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.UIManager;
import javax.swing.UnsupportedLookAndFeelException;

public class Ch3PA extends JFrame {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new Ch3PA();
    }

    public Ch3PA() {
    EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            try {
                UIManager.setLookAndFeel(UIManager.getSystemLookAndFeelClassName());
            } catch (ClassNotFoundException | InstantiationException | IllegalAccessException | UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) {
                ex.printStackTrace();
            }

            JFrame frame = new JFrame("Testing");
            frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
            frame.add(new PaintPanel());
            frame.pack();
            frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
            frame.setVisible(true);
        }
    });
    }

    public class PaintPanel extends JPanel {

        Polygon polygon = new Polygon();
        Point point = new Point(0, 0);
        boolean inside = false;

        public PaintPanel() {

            polygon.addPoint(40, 20);
            polygon.addPoint(70, 40);
            polygon.addPoint(60, 80);
            polygon.addPoint(45, 45);
            polygon.addPoint(20, 60);

            addMouseMotionListener(new MouseAdapter() {
                public void mouseMoved(MouseEvent e) {
                    point.x = e.getX();
                    point.y = e.getY();

                    if (polygon.contains(e.getX(), e.getY())) {
                        inside = true;
                        repaint();
                    } else {
                        inside = false;
                        repaint();

                    }
                }

            });
        }

        @Override
        protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {

            super.paintComponent(g);

            g.drawPolygon(polygon);

            if (inside) {
                g.drawString(inside ? "Mouse point is in the polygon" : "Mouse point is not in the polygon", point.x, point.y);
            }

        }

    }
}
```